# how to explode by backslash (\) in php

Tags: php, explode

I have tried using this below code to explode the backslash `\`, but it is not working. Can anyone please check and update me what need to be added into this, so that i can explode using backslash `\`:

```
explode("\",$ky);
```

rest of the code below to this line is also in dull. so means there is some issue in this syntax.

this also not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is used to escape the literal single colon `'`  [inside of single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) or a [variety of special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in double quoted strings.

Therefore to use the literal `\` you first need to escape the backslash itself  with another backslash like `\\`.

For example:

```
php > $ky = 'Test\\Foo\\Bar';
php > print_r($ky);
Test\Foo\Bar
php > print_r(explode('\\', $ky));
Array
(
    [0] => Test
    [1] => Foo
    [2] => Bar
)
```

Comment: Sorry that makes no sense to me. You have double backslash in the original string. Also "the backslash is used to escape the literal colon". What colon? Once again this does not work with my explode.

Comment: kalehmann - sorry my very bad. I had a major error in code about 2 lines above the place where I was experiencing the // explode problem. Did not put the two together so, unsurprisingly, every explode I tried failed. Once again my apologies.